# Error for token.php related to greeting tokens

Tags: tokens

I keep getting a error daily for one of my cron jobs:

```
Cron <site@prefix> /usr/local/bin/php /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s www.site.org -u adminusername -p adminpassword -e job -a execute
```

The error comes in an email and looks like this:

```
Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1470

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1471

Warning: array_fill_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1471

Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1472
```

It appears to be triggering off greetings.  I have run the job to update greetings but it appears that this is based on what it expects in the code.  Is there something that I need to change in order for the array to get what it expects?

[image: Section of token.php this the error is referring to]

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you were able to get the "Update Greetings" scheduled job to run in cron; the UI specifically disallows enabling that job.  Did you turn it directly using SQL?  You may want to consider whether you really want that job enabled.

That aside - I'd put this line just above line 1470:

```
print_r(CRM_Utils_Array::value($key, $greetingToken), TRUE)
```

And see what you get when you run the cli command manually.

Comment: I now get the error:   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$props' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1471

Comment: Did you add a semi-colon to the end of the statement?

Comment: Thanks, after I added the semi-colon I got the same error:                         Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1471

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1472

Comment: Warning: array_fill_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1472

Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/site/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1473

Comment: Are you running the command outside of cron?  If so, I would expect that you would also receive some additional info that you weren't getting before you added that code.

Comment: I guess I have never done that.  I guess I need to research it and take a look at what additional info I get back.

Comment: An additional observation.  So all my cron jobs inside CiviCRM are running, however I have noticed that Scheduled Reminders is not working.  It shows that it ran but with no success.  When I run it manually, it shows "Success (1)".  So it looks like the token.php error is only affecting the automated running of the Schedule Reminder job but the job runs from inside CiviCRM manually.  Anybody have a clue how this would happen?  Getting tired of having to remember to run the scheduled reminder job everyday.

Comment: Sorry if my last comment was ambiguous.  When I said, "run the command out of cron", I meant, "Take the command that cron is running, and run it on an interactive command line."  You should see more info than is available when the same command runs via cron.

Answer (score 0):

this bug seems to be related to a bug regarding tokens array structure some lines above. The array is being reduced to only one of it's values. Maybe this will work:

See: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17038

Answer (score 0):

I'm also receiving the error: -
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/accountname/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Token.php on line 1472

However, the site is running 4.6.10 so shouldn't it be resolved?

Comment: If you look at Nielo's comment above, the Jira ticket is closed but the fix is scheduled for 4.7 and we are still on 4.6.10.  We just have to wait until January I guess.  Until then the patch works.

Comment: Thanks Hudson, I've applied the patch and it does fix the error.